# Obtener la semana actual empezando en lunes con php

Tags: php, date

Tengo la siguiente duda, como obtener la semana actual comenzando en Lunes, estoy usando la funcion `$week = date('W','02/05/2017');` pero sucede que cuando es domingo me muestra la siguiente semana, es decir si estoy en la semana 5, cuando es domingo ya me muestra la semana 6, y quisiera saber como hacer que el domingo siga siendo semana 5

Me podrian ayudar por favor

Answer (score 3):

Usando la clase [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php):

```
$fecha = new DateTime("02/05/2017");
$semana = $fecha->format('W');
echo "Semana: $semana";

//=> Semana: 05
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff6b97d5c6fb010672bbb5d24af31c7e326f555f)

Answer (score 0):

date() se basa en el calendario gregoriano que consta de 52 semanas comenzando estas el lunes. Con el siguiente código obtenemos la semana actual dentro del año en vigor:

Semana actual, de 1 a 52

usando 
date("W");